# Create empty data frame and fill it with data with different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to create empty pandas data frame with specific number of columns (eg. 50), and filling its rows with columns of other pandas data frames with various columns (less than the destination data frame columns)

Here is what I have done:

I have created empty data frame as follow:

```
L=pd.DataFrame()
```

and fill it with:

```
L.loc[-1]=df1['A']
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined columns
```

I have tried following in order to fill the data frame, but at the end it was empty:

```
L.append(df1['A'])
```

the result of the @Jacob solution is as follow, while the maximum number of `df1['A']` element was only 35. Also, I just want to copy `df1['A']` to the L dataframe, not its column name. how can I prevent it?

```
            3124    3125    3126    3127    3128    3129    3130    3131  \
A  602.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0   
A    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
A    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
A    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
A    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
A    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
A    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   

             3132    3134  ...     38     39     40     41     42     45    \
A -1255.0 -1474.0  ...      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
A     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
A     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
A     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
A     NaN     NaN  ...    127.0 -127.0  143.0  127.0 -143.0    NaN   
A     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  127.0   
A     NaN     NaN  ...      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   

            46     47     48     49    
A    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
A    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
A    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
A    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
A    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
A -143.0    NaN    NaN    NaN  
A    NaN  127.0 -127.0  143.0  
[7 rows x 60 columns]
```

Comment: Did you try `L=L.append(df1['A'])`?

Comment: I get following error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'L' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
L = pd.DataFrame()
L = L.append(df1['A'].transpose())
```

Note that this will use your index from L as your column names, and add those columns if they aren't already present as column labels in L.

Comment: How to name columns as index from 1 to 50?

Comment: if you do `L = L.append(df1['A'].transpose(), ignore_index = True)`, it will name the columns 0 to 49. If you want to make it 1 to 50 you can then do `L.rename(columns = {i: i+1 for i in range(50)}, inplace = True)`.